# Slow timeout 500 msec/cross-node WARNING

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I have a tree node Cassandra cluster.

When I ask lot of data from Java Client, I have the following warnings server-side :

```
 WARN SELECT * FROM [...] time 789 msec - slow timeout 500 msec/cross-node
 WARN SELECT * FROM [...] time 947 msec - slow timeout 500 msec/cross-node
 WARN SELECT * FROM [...] time 1027 msec - slow timeout 500 msec/cross-node
 WARN SELECT * FROM [...] time 819 msec - slow timeout 500 msec/cross-node
```

Client side, I endup with the following exception :

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException:
>   [/x.y.z.a:9042] Connection has been closed

My server configuration yaml is as follow :

```
 # How long the coordinator should wait for read operations to complete
 read_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
 # How long the coordinator should wait for seq or index scans to complete
 range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
 # How long the coordinator should wait for writes to complete
 write_request_timeout_in_ms: 2000
 # How long the coordinator should wait for counter writes to complete
 counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
 # How long a coordinator should continue to retry a CAS operation
 # that contends with other proposals for the same row
 cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
 # How long the coordinator should wait for truncates to complete
 # (This can be much longer, because unless auto_snapshot is disabled
 # we need to flush first so we can snapshot before removing the data.)
 truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
 # The default timeout for other, miscellaneous operations
 request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
```

I **don't find any reference of the "500 ms" timeout**. So how I can tweak this timeout ? Are there any options to avoid ending with Exception when querying large amount of partitions/data ?

*As a side note, I use future to retrieve data the asynchronous-way :*

```
 import com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSetFuture;
```

Comment: "When I ask lot of data from Java Client" - Yeah, don't do that.

Comment: I mean retreiving lot of data from multiples partitions the async way with futures. Each partition follow best practices (<1MB) and are adressed by perfect match on partition key. So what's wrong here ? Could you tell a bit more about your throughs ? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms` is 500 and isnt an actual timeout but just a notification/logging. You can update that in your yaml if you want it higher.

500ms is slow though and may be an indicator that something is wrong in your environment or query. Although if this is rare it may just be periodic GCs which can be mitigated with client side speculative retry.

Comment: Insteresting answer about my first part question. But what about the "connection closed" execution Exception client-side ? I have nothing explicit in server-side logs (except warning I shown in my first post and you explained that it does not matter very well as it not reveal a real timeout that occurs), but my large queries failed client-side with surprising "connection closed" exception .. Thanks!

Comment: did the request actually fail? The client should move it to next host. Theres lots of reasons for that exception including nodes going down (ie from OOM with bad query), network issues, OS configuration issues. Basically a connection reset.